# Script runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that replaces content in a `div` using a menu structure.
This works fine, except it runs multiple times when clicking the various menu items. This makes the page load really slow.

Here is my structure:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.nav-link').click(function(e) {
    var datalist = $(this).data('value');
    var dataname = $(this).data('name');
    console.log(datalist, dataname);
    $(".content_div").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    $(".content_div").load(dataname + ".php");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="top-nav" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active home" href="#" data-value="home" data-name="home">Aanwezig</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-value="vervoer" data-name="vervoer">Vervoer</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-value="extra" data-name="extra">Overige</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content_div">

</div>
```

And a screenshot of the console where you can see the script is multiplying... 
[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be really great...

Comment: Perhaps `$(".content_div").load(dataname+".php");` loads some Javascript that executes Javascript that binds more handlers each time?

Comment: Try to log an event on `$(document).ready()`. I think using load fire this event and then rebind several times your click.

Comment: The code you have posted is working as you expected. So what is the problem?

Comment: @pooyan: Yeah, I've noticed that to. But not on my page. I'm going to build it again and try and figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your js code with the `eventhandler` is loaded more than once. You better figure out why.

Anyway, you can overcome this by using `.off('click').on('click')` (every time the code runs you cancel the existing `eventhandler` (`off()`) and set a new one (`on()`).

`$('a.nav-link').off('click').on('click', function(e){ ...});`

Comment: This solved the problem temporary, will keep looking into the issue tho. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like other already said, the script itself work fine, maybe because your script it's included more than once in your page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.nav-link').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    
    var datalist = $(this).data('value');
    var dataname = $(this).data('name');
    
    console.log('datalist : ', datalist);
    console.log('dataname : ', dataname);
    
    $(".content_div").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    $(".content_div").load(dataname + ".php");
    
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="top-nav" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active home" href="#" data-value="home" data-name="home">Aanwezig</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-value="vervoer" data-name="vervoer">Vervoer</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-value="extra" data-name="extra">Overige</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content_div">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a log statement in your $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Ready');
  $('a.nav-link').click(function(e) {});
});
```

To trace how many the document.ready is called.

To make sure the 'click' event on your link item to be call only once, you can change the code a little bit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Ready');
  $('a.nav-link').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {});
});
```

It is because of calling .click on an item means adding a new event handler on that item, not replacing.